# R/exams appears not returning the right solution of an exam

Tags: r-exams

I have the following question:

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```
```{r, include = FALSE}
correct <- c(
  "A (correct)
  \\vspace{1cm}
  
  $$\\int f\\left(x\\right) dx$$
  
  ", 
  "B (correct)",
  "C (correct)"
)
correct <- sample(correct, 2)

incorrect <- c(
  "D (incorrect)",
  "E (incorrect)",
  "F (incorrect)",
  "G (incorrect)",
  "H (incorrect)",
  "I (incorrect)"
)
incorrect <- sample(incorrect, 6)
```

Question
========
  
Select from the followings items.

\begin{answerlist}
  \item `r correct[1]`
  \item `r correct[2]`
  \item `r incorrect[1]`
  \item `r incorrect[2]`
  \item `r incorrect[3]`
  \item `r incorrect[4]`
  \item `r incorrect[5]`
  \item `r incorrect[6]`
\end{answerlist}

Meta-information
================
exname: My question
extype: mchoice
exsolution: 11000000
exshuffle: TRUE
````

And I use the following code to generate the exam:

```
library(exams)

myexam <- list(
  "question.Rmd",
  "question.Rmd",
  "question.Rmd",
  "question.Rmd"
)

exm <- exams2pdf(myexam,dir = "/tmp/", template = "x.tex")

exm[[1]][[1]]$metainfo$solution
```

where my template is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[portuges]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
\setlength{\parskip}{\bigskipamount}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\setlength\headheight{55pt}
\fancyhf{} % sets both header and footer to nothing
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\newenvironment{answerlist}%
  {\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{(\alph{enumii})}\begin{multicols}{4}\begin{enumerate}}%
  {\end{enumerate}\end{multicols}}

\newenvironment{question}{\item }{}

%\setkeys{Gin}{keepaspectratio}



\begin{document}

This is my exam!

Part 1

\begin{enumerate}
%% \exinput{exercises}
\end{enumerate}

Part 2

\begin{enumerate}[resume]
\input{exercise4}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

However, the solution for my question 1 in the exam is not correct (`exm[[1]][[1]]$metainfo$solution`). Is this a bug? Or am I doing something wrong?

However, the solution for my question 1 in the exam is not correct (`exm[[1]][[1]]$metainfo$solution`). Is this a bug? Or am I doing something wrong?

(Sorry for repeating the last paragraphs, but otherwise Stackoverflow would not allow me to post -- it complains about too much code.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you use a LaTeX-style `{answerlist}` environment in a Markdown exercise. Hence the answer list is not processed correctly internally but it is still rendered but only when doing so via LaTeX (as you do in `exams2pdf()`). If you use `exams2html("question.Rmd")` you see that the answer list is not shown. Unfortunately, no error is thrown, I will check whether this can be improved.

To fix the issue you need to use a Markdown-style question list, either "by hand"

```
Answerlist
----------
* `r correct[1]`
* `r correct[2]`
* `r incorrect[1]`
* `r incorrect[2]`
* `r incorrect[3]`
* `r incorrect[4]`
* `r incorrect[5]`
* `r incorrect[6]`
```

or via the `answerlist()` function (as already shown in: [Questions with a fixed and pre-specified number of true and false answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66766963/questions-with-a-fixed-and-pre-specified-number-of-true-and-false-answers)).

````
```{r, echo = FALSE, results = "asis"}
answerlist(c(correct, incorrect), markup = "markdown")
```
````

Comment: Thanks, Achim, that works! You have simplified a lot the procedure to create random exams. I had already a system working correctly in LyX/LaTeX to randomize exams, but it is too complicated.